# Tracking down where builtin function is being called from in Python

Tags: python, debugging

When I `cProfile` a program I'm working on I see that I'm spending a lot of time making expensive `zip` calls. The code I've written isn't making these zip calls, so it must be in code that I'm bringing in from one of many libraries I've imported.

Is there a tool that will let me flag a function call, and be informed which functions called that function in Python?

Comment: I believe the output of `cProfile` already gives you that information, "hidden" in the cumulative costs of functions. It would be helpful to provide the output of `cProfile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get that information from the profiler output.  Create a [Stats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#the-stats-class) object from the output and call `stats.print_callers('zip')`.

This should show you which functions called it, and for each caller how many times it was called and the total and cumulative times spent in the call.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a problem like yours and I managed to solve it. Its not a *tool* but maybe is useful  for you. Just put the following code at the top of your main module.

**Note:** The code is custom-tailored for the `zip` function you need, for me it works (of course for another function, I don't remember the name now). The extra imports I did was of third party modules in my application, I don't know if it works for modules in the standard library.

```
import inspect

def trackZip(*args):
    print inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]
    return __builtins__.zip(*args)

zip = trackZip

#do more imports...

def test():
    zip([1,2],[3,4])

test()
zip([1,2],[3,4])
```

**Output:**

```
(<frame object at 0x1948260>, '/home/user/untitled4.py', 17, 'test', ['    zip([1,2],[3,4])\n'], 0)
(<frame object at 0x11fd3d0>, '/home/user/untitled4.py', 20, '<module>', ['zip([1,2],[3,4])\n'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A **quick & dirty** way of achieving what you want is pretty simple: *replace the built-in `zip` with a custom function!*

```
In [8]: import inspect
In [9]: def my_zip(*iterables):
   ...:     frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
   ...:     my_zip.callees.append(frame.f_code.co_name)
   ...:     return my_zip.old_zip(*iterables)

In [10]: my_zip.callees = []

In [11]: my_zip.old_zip = zip

In [12]: import builtins

In [13]: builtins.zip = my_zip

In [14]: zip(range(5), range(4))
Out[14]: <builtins.zip at 0x7f06a2324290>

In [15]: zip.callees  # called at module level...
Out[15]: ['<module>']
```

(In python2 replace the `builtins` module with `__builtin__`).

A smarter implementation would use a `collections.Counter` and avoid keeping a list of all function names that called `zip`.

However you may need to know more than the name of the caller of `zip`. Maybe there is an other function `f` that calls `g` that calls `h` that calls `zip`, but to tell that `f` is the real cause of troubles you must relate `h` and `f` somehow.

It shouldn't be hard to extend `my_zip` to keep track of a bit more information though.

---

*However*, I believe that `cProfile`'s output should provide enough timing information to more or less understand where the `zip`s are called. In particular you should carefully study the `cumtime` column of its output.

You should also take into account the number of times the functions are called. Usually a function will always do the same number of `zip`s when called, so the number of calls to `zip` and to the "culprit" function should be proportional in some way.

Surely there can be a lot of noise that hides these relationships but you should try to figure it out.